# Create a Graph of words who differ by 1 char

Tags: java

I have a Map which contains a

- key = length of words
- value = arraylist with words of that length

an example of the map:

- [1] = a, [2] = at, in, it, an, ...

1.User will input wordA

2.User will input wordB

3.Will check if both the same length

4.If yes, a graph will be made with all the words that differ from wordA by 1 letter being adjacent.

5.Then those words that differ from wordA by one letter will be adjacent to words that differ from them by 1 letter. This is done until wordB is reached.

How can I make the graph and adjacency list?

What can I use to find the path from word1 to word2.

Thank you,
Fernando Diaz

Comment: if this is homework tag it as such

Comment: This is identical, aside from the language, to the first problem from the second assignment Stanford's intro C++ course: http://www.stanford.edu/class/cs106b/handouts/13-Assignment-2-ADTs.pdf.  That should help you to break any algorithm block.

Answer (score 0):

In terms of building the path from word1 to word2, this should give you something to start with:

```
    public static List<String> findLadder(String word1, String word2) {
        //invalid request
        if (word1 == null || word2 == null || word1.length() != word2.length()) {
            return Collections.emptyList();
        }

        List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
        List<String> words = dictionary.get(word1.length());
        result.add(word1);

        while (! word1.equals(word2)) {
            String nextWord = null;
            for (int index = 0; index < word1.length(); index++) {
                if (word1.charAt(index) != word2.charAt(index)) {
                    String testWord = word1.substring(0, index) + word2.charAt(index) + word1.substring(index + 1);
                    if (words.contains(testWord)) { 
                        nextWord = testWord;
                        word1 = nextWord;
                        result.add(word1);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            if (nextWord == null) {
                //no mapping exists
                return Collections.emptyList();
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
```

Note that this code will not evaluate any moves that don't move incrementally closer to the desired output, such as `code -> core` when mapping from "code" to "data".  Evaluation of such moves is for you to figure out.

Example here:  http://ideone.com/9JnNH